# How to bind an enum ItemsControl to a Collection in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, enums, itemscontrol

I want to have a list of checkboxes that binds to a collection. So when options are selected, they are added to the list --- when options are deselected, they get removed.

Have tried a number of approaches, but failed to solve this.

**Model**

```
 public enum WeatherType
 {
    Rainy,
    Sunny,
    Cloudy,
    Windy
 }
```

**ViewModel**

```
public class WeatherViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ObservableCollection<WeatherType> WeatherTypes {get;set;}
    ...
}
```

**XAML**

```
 <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="weather"
            MethodName="GetValues"
            ObjectType="{x:Type sys:Enum}">
    <ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
    <x:Type TypeName="business:WeatherType" />
    </ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
</ObjectDataProvider>

...

<ItemsControl Grid.Row="4"
      Grid.Column="1"
      ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource weather}}">
<ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
    <StackPanel />
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
<ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <CheckBox Content="{Binding}" />
    </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare a view model for weather type:

```
public class WeatherTypeViewModel
{
    public WeatherType WeatherType { get; set; }
    public bool IsChecked { get; set; }
}
```

Change your view model like this:

```
public class WeatherViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ObservableCollection<WeatherTypeViewModel> WeatherTypes {get;set;}
    ...
}
```

and view - like this:

```
<ItemsControl Grid.Row="4"
      Grid.Column="1"
      ItemsSource="{Binding WeatherTypes}">
<ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
    <StackPanel />
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
<ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <CheckBox Content="{Binding WeatherType}" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}"/>
    </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```